# vbscripting: using Or in a If...Then... Else statement

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm using UFT and I have to make sure that my script doesn't take a particular move when I compare the string with either of the two values. But I am having a problem.

Please suggest a solution.

Here's my script:

```
If (Role<>"Super Admin" Or Role<>"MR") Then
    obj2.WebList("html id:=Audit").Select AuditId
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Role` can only hold a single value then the statement `(Role<>"Super Admin" Or Role<>"MR")` will always be `TRUE`. I think, instead, you want `AND`:

```
If (Role<>"Super Admin" AND Role<>"MR") Then
    obj2.WebList("html id:=Audit").Select AuditId
End If
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill... Ur clarification and solution helped.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks for editing my question... request u to let me know how can I edit my questions before posting to reduce ur work.